# Unable to debug code on pycharm as gunicorn worker times out

Tags: python, debugging, pycharm

Whenever I try to test & debug my api functions on pycharm, this error pops up and the gunicorn server restarts. Is there any workaround for this?

```
[2018-12-26 12:47:16 +0000] [13596] [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:14527)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "_pydevd_bundle/pydevd_cython.pyx", line 750, in _pydevd_bundle.pydevd_cython.PyDBFrame.trace_dispatch
    self.do_wait_suspend(thread, frame, event, arg)
  File "_pydevd_bundle/pydevd_cython.pyx", line 254, in _pydevd_bundle.pydevd_cython.PyDBFrame.do_wait_suspend
    self._args[0].do_wait_suspend(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/pycharm-community-2018.3.2/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 877, in do_wait_suspend
    time.sleep(0.01)
  File "/home/bhargav/.venvs/icv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 196, in handle_abort
    sys.exit(1)
SystemExit: 1
```

Comment: Could it be an infinite loop? Can you breakpoint the very first lien and step through? Or does this happen when brealkpointing the first line?

Comment: I doubt it's an infinite loop. I've break pointed the very first line of my api function and as long as I am constantly spamming F8 button (step over), it works fine. But If I stop even for a sec to inspect the values of variables, this error is thrown and the server restarts.

Comment: I don't know much about gunicorn, but I think there is some wait-time value that I need to change so that the worker doesn't immediately timeout.

Comment: Why are you using [Gunicorn](https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/), and do the docs help? Since you are on Linux, what's wrong with a standard [Apache server](https://httpd.apache.org/)? You will certainly find more support for it.

Comment: Our application back-end is deployed on a remote server using gunicorn so I've used it on my local dev env as well to maintain consistency. I have just switched to using 'bjoern' locally and it seems to working for now. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Feel free to answer and accept your own question, if you have an answer which might help others in future. Welcome aboard :-)

Answer (score 1):

run your app with time out param e.g.

`gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:5000 --log-level=debug -t 300` for 5 mins

[gunicorn doc](https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/settings.html#timeout)